# CSS: One column's width relative to resizable 100% height square?

Tags: css

This question is kind of hard so explain so I've created a jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/zLjHn/ (or see HTML/CSS below)

Basically I want a square shaped video on the right size of the screen with 100% height and the left column to fill the rest of the available screen space. I've been working on this problem for a few hours so any help would be appreciated!

**Edit:** Left column will contain a number of paragraphs/images that will be centered in the available space (not just a single paragraph as the example code shows.

CSS:

```
.profile_page {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
.left {
    float:left;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
video {
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    border: 1px solid red;
    float: right;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    max-width: 80%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="profile_page">
    <div class="left">
        <p>This paragraph's width should adjust according to the videos width.</p>
    </div>

    <video src="http://stream.flowplayer.org/trains/640x360.mp4" /> 
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: I actually find myself unable to help, that JS Fiddle's crashed Chrome (or that particular tab, at least) four times out of four attempts.

Comment: @DavidThomas That's strange, I'm using Chrome and have no issues.

Comment: Well, I'm visiting folks, so I'm on 32bit Win XP, rather than my own machine. So, whatever's going on might just be a limitation in the age of the machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taboo as this sounds, your answer is a table layout.  A two-cell table row exhibits the layout behavior you're looking for without any javascript.  If you're concerned about semantic HTML (and you should be) you can accomplish this using `display:table-cell;` and `display:table-row;` in your css.

**This will limit the browsers that correctly display your layout.**

```
<div class="profile_page">
    <div class="left">
        <p>This paragraph's width should adjust according to the videos width.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <video src="http://stream.flowplayer.org/trains/640x360.mp4" /> 
    </div>
</div>
```

and the style...

```
.profile_page {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    display:table-row;
}
.left {
    min-width: 100px;
    display:table-cell;
    border:1px solid green;
    vertical-align:top;
}
.right
{
    display:table-cell;
    border:1px solid blue;
    max-width:80%;
    min-width:300px;
}
video {
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

See the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NkeLc/1/

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a quick fix, you can reorganize to wrap the `<p>` around the video like this: http://jsfiddle.net/zLjHn/4/

I believe the paragraph and video are competing for "flexibility".  Seems like you want the video to flex according to height, and the paragraph to then flex with available width.

I think you can achieve the right flex-priority by leading with the video and wrapping the paragraph around it as the attached fiddle shows.

Comment: Solution is great for one paragraph but the left column will contain a few elements (paragraphs + images) which I'm hoping to center in the available space.

Comment: Not sure how to get the image to flex, but here's a start: http://jsfiddle.net/zLjHn/6/

Comment: I think the OP wants to have more than just text wrap, all in one `div`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify your **CSS** as following:

```
.left {
    float:left;
    max-width:20%;
    position: relative;
    min-width: 100px;
}
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4yEmJ/

Comment: This doesn't adjust the left column, it just sets its width to 20%. If you drag the height of the demo on jsfiddle to the smallest possible you will see what I mean.